# How to remove the trailing slash from the base url codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My home page url is http://localhost:8080/myproj/
I need to remove the trailing slash 
How do I do that ?

Because, when I remove index.php(using htaccess), the url becomes http://localhost:8080/myproj//projects/list 
The url needs to be this way http://localhost:8080/myproj/projects/list

Please help

Comment: how you produce this `http://localhost:8080/myproj//projects/list`. show code.

Comment: using  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]                                          in htaccess

Comment: no, I am saying what function you used. `site_url()` or `base_url()`? provide this code

Comment: used site_url()

Comment: perhaps you using like this `echo site_url().'/projects/list'`

Comment: yes right oook Thanks a lot !!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code should as following

```
echo site_url('projects/list')
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

This guide should be helpful.. http://www.htaccess-guide.com/

Answer (score 0):

In the config directory open the config.php file and check base URL should be as

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://yoursite.com/';
```

and now access any controller like this:-

```
echo site_url('controller/function');
```